# Two desktops running a windows form application shared on a network folder is slow and lags

Tags: c#, windows, networking, directory, shared

My name is Grant and I am just graduating college and I have been working on a little reservation system for a campground and I am running into some issues with speed. I know my code is not perfect, but I do believe I have done a pretty good job at writing a nice, neat, organized program.

Right now how I run the application is by storing it on a shared network folder on one of the desktops, and then I run the application from the shared folder on the other desktop. The *ISSUE* I am having is that there seems to be a little bit of or its slow sometimes. Its almost like the computer cant keep up. Which is strange, because when you run the application on the desktop where the application is actually being shared from, the application works great. Its fast and responsive. So that makes me believe my code is fine because it runs great on that computer so it cant be my code. Which leads me to believe that its either my network(which I also have a hard time believing, because we have no problems streaming multiple things at the same time). We have never had any problems lately with internet speed. So where I am at now is could it possibly be the desktop itself. They are both pretty cheap desktops running the app. If I upgraded and bought two new desktop computers would the speed increase at all?

Any help or advice on the issue would be great. The application is working likes its suppose to, but the speed of it needs to be picked up. If anyone has any advice at all I would very much appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you not install it on a fast computer and then give users access to remote desktop into it? If it is internal to your network, that can be an option. Also, have you tried running it and testing it on this "cheap` desktop you are referring to without accessing from the network folder?

Comment: Be sure to check your antivirus and firewall settings.  Try disabling them temporarily both and test again.  You might try posting on serverfault.com as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Comment: I will try both of them and get back to you.